# windows.location.href is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, href, innerhtml, window.location

this is my HTML code

```
<select name="chart" id="cart" onchange="GetVal(this)">

<option value="tree" selected>collapsiable tree</option> <option value="sun">sunburst</option><option value="icicle">icicle</option> </select>
```

this is the javascript code used for page navigation

```
function GetVal(val) {
var selectedText = val.options[val.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
var selectedValue = val.value;
if(selectedValue=="sun")window.location.href = "sun.html";

if(selectedValue=="icicle")window.location.href = "icicle.html";
```

}

but this is not working when I use javascript...how do I change the url...plz help

Comment: That is Java Script code. It runs on the client (browser) and has nothing to do with Flask.

Comment: option does not have innerHTML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: Try adding a slash before each, e.g. `"\sun.html"`